# Dompdf add PDF-image on PDF

Tags: dompdf

I have a logo in .PDF format CMYK, how do I apply this to the HTML/PHP page and include it in the final generated PDF-document?

I know I can include .png image, but it wont turn out well on print.

Comment: JPEG can hold CMYK colors. But I am not sure PHP won't recompress the JPEG and PHP most likely cannot handle CMYK images.

Comment: The CMYK is vectorized in .PDF so you can zoom in on it, a normal image would become blurry.

Comment: I am not sure you can do this in DomPDF. I worked with JPEGs, GIFs and PNG always. Didn't really sea a way to use something else. You can try using hi-res JPEG image. You can also switch to FPDF and just embed the PDF in your PHP-generated PDF: http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

Comment: @Tom is right, dompdf currently only works with standard HTML image formats (JPG, GIF, PNG) and some other common formats (BMP). I can see this being useful, but right now it's not possible with dompdf. We have a request to [support embedded (and linked) SVG](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/320). You might want to [add a request](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/new) to support other vector formats (like PDF, EPS, etc).